# PLL integrated CCC, Microsemi/Actel ProASIC3 nano Flash Family FPGA, A3P125

Tags: fpga, pll, actel

I have Micosemi/Actel ProASIC3 Nano A3P125,VQ100 Chip. I was looking for the PLL integrated CCC to connect 100MHz Clock and I have been through the manual ***ProASIC3 FPGA Fabric User’s Guide***. where i have found, i have three options(3pins) like "GFA0, GFA1 or GFA2". It's clear from manual that '*Only one of the I/Os can be directly connected to a chip global at a time*'.

what about the rest of two pins? Can I use them as output?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use those pins for GPIO when you don't need their special functions.